# Control what custom posts a user can see

Tags: custom-post-types, users, user-roles

I've been looking into user roles and it would seem that there are 100 plugins to help me control what a user can edit or publish but they don't get any more specific.

We have a custom post type called Chapters and we have hundreds of users who can view said Chapters.  What we want to do is add a new user role that can only view certain posts within the Chapters post type. So we have 51 Chapters and we only want the new role to see 31 of the 51 chapters.

EDIT: I'm talking about the front-end. Our site requires subscription to access it so the new user role would be a like a subscriber, only they couldn't see specific "Chapters"

Comment: View on the front end? How is this meant to work?

Comment: Oh sorry should specify.  Yes, on the front end.  Users can only get into our site by being registered.  So new users under this new role I'm describing will only be able to see specific "Chapters"

Comment: Thanks. Can you edit that into the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using plugins like [Paid Memberships PRO](https://wordpress.org/plugins/paid-memberships-pro/) or [s2member](https://wordpress.org/plugins/s2member/) would be easiest solution for your purpose. You can create new user group and there capabilities. After that you can select which user group can see your post.